# SaaS Starter Kit For ASP.NET to Cover Subscription, Billing etc

Tags: asp.net, saas

I am about to start on a new project, and I am seriously considering going down the SaaS route, rather than having it desktop based. I know it is a lot more work to start with, getting everything set up, however, I feel the benefits of SaaS for the type of project being undertaken weigh heavily in its favour. No need to worry about people cracking the software, easier to update on a client by client basis, rolling out updates etc. My experience is almost completely with desktop applications, C#, Java etc.

I am wanting to use visual studio, asp.net web application to develop the software, and have been looking into hosting solutions such as azure, Amazon etc to host. However, my problem at the moment is working out whether everything will need to be coded by me.

Is there a framework, template type thing that can be used as a base for SaaS applications? Something that I can build my application on so I can just worry about my program. Ideally it would be something that will handle to subscription levels, automated billing etc. As well as creating the databases (I will be using the multi-tenancy architecture) for each client automatically, and setting up the subdomains for the logins (e.g. companyname.myappsite.com)

I would prefer not to use an external service, as it may cause problems if I ever choose to switch suppliers, and they hold all my customer billing info, causing me to ask all my clients to sign back up. I would like to host everything myself.

Wondering if anyone knows of anything that I could use that would cover the above? Either in one solutions, or using a mixture. I know the above covers a wide range of features, however, this type of thing exists all over the net, as SaaS is becoming ever more popular, and I just cant see all of these companies writing all this themselves, however, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [techcello.com](http://techcello.com). They have built a SaaS framework in .NET covering all of your requirements from tenant on-boarding, subscription, billing, trial management, notifications, data backup and much more which can be used to kick-start any SaaS product.

As per you requirement you have complete control of your data since they just provide you the binaries and you need to host it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the free / open-source [AspDotNetBoilerPlate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) and paid [AspNet Zero](https://aspnetzero.com/) boilerplate frameworks. Combined together, you get a full-stack starter kit for building SaaS applications in .NET including multi-tenant architecture, logins, host / tenant configuration, logging, chat, responsive MVC website and more.